# Is it a good idea to directly use foreach expression on XPathNavigator.Select?

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

I reached the following code in an application:

```
XPathNavigator item = nav.SelectSingleNode("foo");
foreach (XPathNavigator n in item.Select("bar"))
{

}
```

The code works but I wonder if caching Select method yields much faster code, so I rewrote it as follows:

```
XPathNavigator item = nav.SelectSingleNode("foo");
XPathNodeIterator it = item.Select("bar");
while (it.MoveNext())
{

}
```

So, What do you think? Are these 2 pieces of code identical or not?

Comment: My usual way of finding out of something is slowing my code down, is to run it that way, and see if it takes longer. Did you try that?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". In this case, you can easily run the two pieces of code as @EdPlunkett describes, or compile them both and inspect the IL produced to see if it is identical. Neither of which requires anyone else...